# No me funciona la animación, ni siquiera el nombre es valido en css

Tags: html, css

No se que pasa, ya revise que todo estuviera bien, he intentado cambiar los nombres de animación, tamaño de pixeles eh incluso comportamiento en el `@Keyframes`, pero aun nada.

Me gustaria pensar que definí mal el nomber o que cometí algún error a la hora de poner el before

agradezco cualquier ayuda, comentario y consejo. Adjunto mi código:

```css
button{
  background: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 12px;
  margin: 10px 150px;
  text-align: center;
}

button::before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(
    45deg,
    red, blue, deeppink,blue,
    red, blue, deeppink, blue
  );
  background-size: 800%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  filter: blur(8px);
  animation: glowing 20s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes glowing {
  0%{
    background-position: 0 0; 
  }
  50%{
    background-position: 400% 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<article>
  <button>Call me</button>
</article>
```

Comment: Buen día, ¿Cuál es el inconveniente?, yo veo que si funciona tu animación...

Comment: A mi si me funciona la aminación incluso antes de haber sido editado, entiendo que lo tienes en un archivo `style.css` porque tu html hace referencia a él. Lo único que podría estar fallando es que tenga mal el nombre el archivo css o que este en otra carpera y no a la par del html.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que editaron tu código, ¿pero realmente tenías la parte de CSS dentro del mismo archivo? Si es así, tienes que colocar el código CSS dentro de las etiquetas  o dentro del archivo style.css que referencias en el código HTML

## CSS Inline

Definir directamente las propiedades de estilo sobre la etiqueta *(no recomendable, a menos que emplees alguna librería o componente que te permita gestionar la especificad de esto, o sepas muy bien lo que haces)

## CSS Interno

Definir uno o varios estilos agrupados dentro de etiquetas `<style></style>`. De esa manera, en un mismo archivo tienes presentación y estructura.

## CSS Externo

Traslada las definiciones de estilo a un archivo por fuera del marcado de etiquetas, tal cual tienes en tu ejemplo, con `<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`. Para ese caso, el navegador buscará en el archivo style.css en la misma carpeta los estilos correspondientes.

## Código funcional

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <style>
        button{
        background: black;
        cursor: pointer;
        border: none;
        padding: 8px 20px;
        color: white;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: bold;
        position: relative;
        border-radius: 12px;
        margin: 10px 150px;
        text-align: center;
    }


    button::before{
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: -1;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: linear-gradient(
        45deg,
         red, blue, deeppink,blue,
          red, blue, deeppink, blue
        );
        background-size: 800%;
        border-radius: 10px;
        filter: blur(8px);
        animation: glowing 20s linear infinite;
    }


    @keyframes glowing {
        0%{
            background-position: 0 0; 
        }
        50%{
            background-position: 400% 0;
        }
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <article>
        <button>Call me</button>    
    </article>
```

Comment: Mmm... pareciese que pegó mal el código en la pregunta, yo solo lo acomodé en un snippet para que el código sea reproducible...

Comment: El espíritu de la edición es excelente, creo que se corrige accidentalmente el bug al separar el HTML del CSS en el snippet. Es mi interpretación de la pregunta original.